# Jqplot in Rails - Point Labels are Missing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, charts, jqplot

My jqplot graphs work perfectly with the crucial exception of point labels, which I cannot get to show even using the basic simple examples from the [jqplot website](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/point-labels.php).

One of the examples from the above I have put in my `index.html.erb` file:

```
<div id="chart1" style="height:400px;width:300px; "></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var line1 = [14, 32, 41, 44, 40, 47, 53, 67];
  var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
      title: 'Chart with Point Labels', 
      seriesDefaults: { 
        showMarker:false,
        pointLabels: { show:true } 
      }
  });
});
</script>
```

This should produce a line graph with labels on each point, but what I get is:

[image: Example of No Point Labels]

I have tried ~10 examples from different people who implement points labels in slightly different ways, with no success.

In Rails I use the `jqplot-rails` gem, but the results are the same. Does anyone know what this means? I have tried including:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqplot.com/src/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqplot.com/src/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqplot.com/src/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqplot.com/src/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqplot.com/src/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>
```

Immediately before the above code snippet (to makes sure I am using the latest jqplot), but it makes no difference.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.